# Laravel Validation – Date Format m/y Not Accepting Specific Value

Tags: php, laravel, validation, date, laravel-5.4

I've got the following validation rules for basic authentication of a Payment Method (advanced things, like CVD validation, existing card, etc. is handled afterward by Moneris).

```
$rules = [
    "type" => "required|in:visa,mastercard",
    "nickname" => "required",
    "credit_card_number" => "required|numeric|digits:16",
    "expiry" => "required|string|size:5|date_format:m/y|after:today",
    "cvd" => "required|numeric|digits:3"
];
```

The rule `expiry` is not accepting a specific value, `04/yy`, but it is accepting `03/yy` and `05/yy`; I have no idea why this is happening, but I need it remedied. Has anyone come across this behaviour?

For reference, the result `dd($request->input(), $validator->passes(), $validator->errors());` when I pass `04/19` is as follows:

```
array:6 [▼
  "type" => "visa"
  "nickname" => "Testing"
  "credit_card_number" => "4242424242424242"
  "expiry" => "04/19"
  "cvd" => "123"
  "masked_pan" => "************4242"
]
false
MessageBag {#502 ▼
  #messages: array:1 [▼
    "expiry" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "The expiry does not match the format m/y."
    ]
  ]
  #format: ":message"
}
```

When I send `05/19`, everything works fine:

```
array:6 [▼
  "type" => "visa"
  "nickname" => "Testing"
  "credit_card_number" => "4242424242424242"
  "expiry" => "05/19"
  "cvd" => "123"
  "masked_pan" => "************4242"
]
true
MessageBag {#502 ▼
  #messages: []
  #format: ":message"
}
```

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? Possibly related to this: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/21467

Comment: poking around some threads, I see users putting quotes around `date_format:"m/y"` like here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/date-format-validation does that change anything?

Comment: Sorry, Laravel 5.4 is the version. And I'll try that Jeff; see if anything different happens.

Comment: @Jeff If I do `date_format:\"y/m\"`, it treats it as the same. If I use single quotes, it fails for `05/19`. If I swap the quotes it still fails. I don't think that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's an issue with how this validation rule works in Laravel 5.4. To fix, I check the date validity of the input prepended with `01/`, and if it is valid, merge that into the request, with `endOfMonth()` to handle `after:today` validation:

```
$mergeDate = null;
$rawInput = $request->input("expiry");
try {
    $mergeDate = Carbon::createFromFormat("d/m/y", "01/".$request->input("expiry"))->endOfMonth();  
} catch(\Exception $ex){}

$request->merge([
    "masked_pan" => str_repeat("*", 12).substr($request->input("credit_card_number", ""), -4),
    "expiry" => $mergeDate ? $mergeDate->format("d/m/y") : $request->input("expiry")
]);
```

So now, if I pass `04/22`, it will check if `01/04/22` is valid, then convert to end of month `30/04/22`, then replace that as the value passed to the validation (which also needs to be updated)

```
"expiry" => "required|string|size:8|date_format:d/m/y|after:today",
```

I also have to update and pass `$messages` to avoid confusion to the user:

```
$messages = [
    "expiry.size" => "The :attribute filed must be 5 characters.",
    "expiry.date_format" => "The :attribute field does not match the format m/y"
];

$validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);
```

And finally, replace the value with the raw input if there's an error (so the user doesn't see a value they didn't enter)

```
if(!$validator->passes()){
    $request->merge(["expiry" => $rawInput]);
    return back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
}
```

A whole bunch of nonsense, but seems to handle `04/22` and other dates just fine.